# Notepad ++ Perform Search Replace On All Lines Except Last

Tags: regex, notepad++

In **Notepad++**, I often have the requirement of performing a regex-based search and replace on multiple lines. However, I would like to keep the last line intact.

Simplistic example below:

Sample File

```
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
Line Three
```

Regex:

```
(.*)
```

Replace With:

```
\1,
```

The required result should be as below:

```
Line One,
Line Two,
Line Three,
Line Three
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to capture just the line endings, and then replacing with a comma + the captured newline symbol:

Find what: `([\r\n]+)`

Replace with: `,\1`

In case you have a blank/empty last line, and you still do not need to add a comma at the end of the last *non*-empty line, use this regex in Find what:

```
([\r\n]+)(?!\s*$)
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 1):

This will group the line text in the first group and the new line feed in the second group, so you can do more replacement easily

Find :

```
(.*)(?=[\r\n])
```

replace with:

```
\1,
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Capture line and ending, insert a comma in the replacement.

Find:  `(.*)(\r?\n)`
Repl:  `$1,$2`

If you want to get fancy, you can add comma's to only lines that do not end in comma's.

```
 # (?m)^((?!.*,[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n).*)(\r?\n)

 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^     
 (                             # (1 start), line data
      (?! .* , [^\S\r\n]* \r? \n )
      .* 
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( \r? \n )                    # (2), line ending
```